# how to use nested map function with bootstrap table?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dictionary, bootstrap-table, array-map

i am having an error with below code. it shows module build failed. I think the structure is missing some tag

```
<tbody>
          {
            ListItems.map((section) =>
              <tr key={section.id}>
                <td>{section.name}</td>
              </tr>
                  {
                section.items.map((item) =>
                
                  <tr key={item.id}> // the error is here
                    <td>{item.productName}</td>
                  </tr>
                )})}
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proper paranthesis and wrap everything inside fragment as follows.

```
<tbody>
  {
    ListItems.map((section) => (
      <Fragment key={section.id}>
        <tr key={section.id}>
          <td>{section.name}</td>
        </tr>
          {
             section.items.map((item) => (
               <tr key={item.id}>
                   <td>{item.productName}</td>
               </tr>
             )
           }
      </Fragment>
      )
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: I tried this. but i have key error

Comment: Try this and also post the exact error.

Comment: react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `PriceList`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at PriceList
    at div
    at App

Comment: This is a warning, means that items do not have unique id.

Comment: i got a solution by adding <React.Fragment key={section.id}> instead of empty tag